# Google `drive.files.list` doesn't list files

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, service-accounts, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm having issues with the Google drive API. I am passing in the folder ID and it's not showing any files. How do I traverse within the sub folders to check for folders and files there?

```
const path = require('path')
const { JWT } = require('google-auth-library')
const { google } = require('googleapis')
const axios = require('axios')

// Get auth token
const getAuth = ({ email, key }) => {
  const scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
  return new JWT({
    email,
    key,
    scopes,
  })
}

async function loadDrive(options) {
  const { folderId, key, service_email } = options
  const auth = await getAuth({ email: service_email, key })

  const drive = google.drive({
    version: 'v3',
    auth: auth,
  })

  try {
    const res = await drive.files.list({
      pageSize: 10,
      fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
      q: `'${folderId}' in parents`,
      spaces: 'drive',
    })

    const files = res.data.files
    if (files.length === 0) {
      console.log('No files found.')
    } else {
      console.log('Files:')
      for (const file of files) {
        console.log(`${file.name} (${file.id})`)
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the full message?  any errors

Comment: I'm seeing a `status: 200,  statusText: 'OK', data: { files: [] }` it's just not returning files. I'm not sure if I'm setting it up correctly. Maybe from the query or the console side?

Comment: From your script, it seems that you are using the service account. I have a question. In your situation, the folder of your `folderId` is the folder in the drive of the service account or the folder shared with your account? Or is the folder where is not shared with your account? Or another folder?

Comment: Ah! Yes, I just tried adding the service account email to the Drive folder and now it's working. It looks like I needed to provide access to that service account email first. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**[Update 01/04/22]:** I shared my service account email under https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts with the folder in Google drive and was able access the Drive data.

[image]